# Override system library in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to override the headers that Xcode uses for a specific third party library because the one bundled with OS X / Xcode is out of date and am having trouble getting Xcode to choose the correct headers.

Right now the library is included via `#include <pcap/pcap.h>`. I can't change this because the code is cross platform and this is where the library should be. I have the latest version of the libpcap library headers  located at ~/software/pcap/. Including `~/software/` in the "Header Search Paths" results in my other third party libraries (that don't exist at the system level) being found and used, but Xcode is still using the bundled/internal (old) version of the libpcap headers. I've tried adjusting the order in which the "Header Search Paths" list is set up with no luck.

I've tried "always search user paths" but this results in dozens and dozens of other local project headers being substituted for system/other library headers. I only want the headers for this specific library to override the system ones.

Is there a way to force Xcode to use a non-bundled set of library headers in place of the bundled ones for a single specific library?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Xcode does not follow aliases. Replacing the alias with actual files & folders and ensuring that the "Header Search Path" order has your overridden files listed before the Xcode level ones seems to resolve this issue.